# Can I read and write data on same firebase real-time database using flutter and python?

Tags: python, firebase, flutter

I want to write a data on firebase using Python and also through flutter. So can I do this on same database (only one)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Yes, you can.

Answer (score 1):

You can you need the [Firebase Python SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/python) to access to your firestore database.